# Auto-launched flow that creates Activities works in Classic, fails with GACK in LEX

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-experience

Simple use case

1. Create an SObject (`Case`) using the UI + Save button
2. Start a Process on Create that invokes an auto-launched flow
3. Auto-launched flow creates *n* (12) Tasks using Fast Create, assigned to an active userId

> Run in Classic - works fine, all tasks created
>
> Run in LEX, Case is created but the flow gacks

Answer (score 1):

*Posting answer as this required a support case to resolve*

SFDC Level 2 Support looked up the gack (**without me even having to prompt them** ) and the problem is a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XAoAAM)

```
Flow Error, INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'NotifDeliveryUserPref' is not supported
```

There is only one workaround:

```
Settings | Customize | Activities | Activity Settings
```

then uncheck the box for `Enable user control over task assignment notifications`

This feature was rolled out in Winter 15 and the [release notes for it are here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_sales_activities_notifications_task_assignment.htm).

*Side note (at least as of this writing - October 16), the Known Issue can't be found by [searching the Known Issues site](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?page=6&tag=Flow).*

Comment: Can't be found via search. That's fun.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I used to be arrogant enough that I would assert that one doesn't need Premier Support as all problems in SFDC are self-curable with enough research and experimentation. I have lost all such arrogance as the platform has become very complex and issues like the above took me all of 5 seconds to decide to file a support case.